# How do I connect to an HP 1910 switch console from GNU screen?

Tags: hp, hp-procurve, linux, cli

I'm trying to use GNU screen on Ubuntu 14.04 to connect to an HP 1910-8G switch console but it is not working. So far for all of my attempts, screen seems to terminate or just appears blank. Has anyone tried this before? What command did you issue to get it working?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it working with this command

```
sudo screen /dev/ttyS0 38400,cs8,-ixon,ixoff
```

Before running the command, I had to use `dmesg` to find which of the ttyS or ttyU devices was to be used.

Also the parameters after the ttyS device are the exact ones specified in the the HP 1910 manuals.

There are other programs such as cu and minicom. I chose GNU screen because it was already a familiar tool. The minicom program seems to have a lot of features bu GNU screen has almost zero learning curve for me. The simplest program for me is cu, doesn't it work so great on Ubuntu - it does work well on FreeBSD and Apple OS X.